# Unexpectedly able to delete storage container having running VHDs

Tags: azure, cloud-storage

Today I deleted an Azure storage container that contained some `.vhd`s page blobs.

Some of the blobs were the source for some VM disks that were attached to *running* VM's.

I was surprised that the delete operation worked and even more surprised that the VM's haven't missed a beat.

I shut the VM's down and exported the Disk images successfully.

I've read **a lot** of accounts of people **not able** to delete leased blobs because they were the source of attached disks, but I seem to be experiencing the opposite: it was waaaay too easy to delete the container having these VHD blobs.

What is going on here? Why does everything still work?

Comment: It's totally clear what I'm asking.  Question marks coming after words at the bottom.  Plenty of context above the questions.  Mods, please for the love of God, there's no reason to try closing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still can't. What happened is that you probably migrated the disks from unmanaged to managed. The original VHDs still sits in the storage if you haven't deleted it, but they won't be serving your VM anymore. The fact that you could export the disks confirms that you are using managed disks.

**Update**:

A quick way to verify that you have managed disks is to look for the disk resource usually sitting in the same resource group as your VM:

[image]

Comment: How can I confirm that? If they were migrated to managed wouldn't I cease seeing the source blob when looking at the disk in the portal? I did nothing to my knowledge that would cause a switch to managed disks.

Comment: You just need to confirm that you have managed disks. That's all. If that's the case, your VHDs (disks) do not sit in a storage account as they are fully managed by Microsoft. You don't need to deploy a Storage account at all to have a Virtual Machine up and running on a managed disk. The export button is only available to VMs with managed disks. You can also go to the portal -> VM -> select disks -> click on a disk and check the header to see if it says "unmanaged" after the name of the disk. If you see a whole new set of buttons like export, create snapshot, etc. then it's a managed disk.

Comment: managed disks also appear as a resource in your resource group list. You will see a disk resource type usually with the same name as the VM.